# How to get google fit app data using google fit api in php?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

I want to integrate google fit api in Php Laravel framework.Please Let me know how can i synchronize google fit app data in my php website ?

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to call an any Auth2 based google api**

```
#Before hitting an api and getting data from a google we have to 
authenticate our application and then we hit an api to get data.Go 
through below steps.   

Step1 : Get credentials

#Before calling an api you must needed a google developer account where
```

you will get your credentials to hit an     api,Perform below steps,
(1) Go to link - https://console.cloud.google.com/
(2) Create google developer account and create new project
(3) Configure consent screen
(4) Click on + CREATE CREDENTIALS and choose OAuth Client ID(if api is auth based) and follow steps they provides.

```
#after these steps you will find your credentials - this credentials will 
 be used for authentication & to hit an api.

***Step2 : Get an authorization code***

  # To get an authorization code you need to hit an simply below URL by 
   appending some parameters.see example below
   
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/    auth?redirect_uri={$redirect_uri}&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id={$client_id}&scope={$scope}&access_typ    e=offline;
 
 =>Parameter Description

  $redirect_url : URL which you have set while creating a project
  $client_id : client id is user id of whom you will get data.
  $scope : What data do you wants to get.you will find all google scopes here 'https://developers.google.com/identity/    protocols/oauth2/scopes' choose your relevent scope

 #after hitting URL and by following provided steps you will be redirect to the URL which you have appended in     url(This url should same as which url you have set while creating a project,check in your account to find this     url),in above example $redirect_uri variabale contains redirect url.After hitting an URL you will get     below(NOTE:below url will be your $redirect url but this time with authorization code will be appended url you will     get),

http://localhost/abc/bcd/redirect-google-fit.php?code=4/    errktltllt5jyjYrunfa6bue9wRcQ8YufKihn6ozHT6xd0Jhr6QsrA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/    fitness.body.read%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read

***Step3 : Get an Access Token***
  
# before getting data from google fit we have to authenticate our application
# Make a CURL request to get an access token,use below code by replacing your relevent variables.

    $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
  ));

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    die();
  }
  curl_close($ch);

  $response = json_decode($data);
------------------------------
  #Parameters description -  client_secret : You will get this from you credentials section in google developer     console,
                             client_id : wlll be your client primary id
                             redirect_url : will be your redirect url as disccused above.


***Step4 : Hit an API***

  #First step is to select data source.
  #You can find it from google cloud api or make a CURL request with below url 

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/(data source)

#here,(data source) means the data you would like to get e.g. weight data,steps data etc..
#In response you will get diff data sources, choose relevent one and append it in like below shown.
 
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/    derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight/datasets/

or you can also apply time filter to get data from range,like below.

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/    derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight/datasets/(time in miliseconds)

***Step 5 : Final step is to hit an API***
 
#full code to hit api

  $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/    derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight/datasets/".$date_filter[$r]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
      die();
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $data_arr = json_decode($data);

    And Finally $data_arr will contain data.


NOTE:#CURL_URL will be your data source url which we get in step4.
     #headers contains Content-type , $token etc..
     #token will be we have get in step3.
     #date filter is used to get data from date range.
```